# Retrieve data from spring doesn't work after insert

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem when I insert data in my MySQL database with Spring Data Jpa Module.

The problem is the following:
When I startup my Springapplication I create the database and initialize the data with SpringdataJPA and I see the data inserted in the table. Afterwards i wanna insert some data related to inserted data and only 1 of the 3 records inserted before were found. When i restard the server and i dont recreate the data and search for it with the same method every single record is found. I search for 2 weeks for a solution but didnt find anything. I hope you can help me.

**NEWS**

I think only in words is hard to understand, so I insert the code behind. jpa.xml with all spring jpa configuration. The 2 entities and the initmethods. hopefully you can find my error.

**jpa.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:properties/database/database.properties" />
<!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities--> 
<!-- BoneCP configuration -->   
<bean id="SoopDataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
   <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driver}" />
   <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}" />
   <property name="username" value="${database.user}"/>
   <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
   <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60"/>
   <property name="idleMaxAge" value="240"/>
   <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="30"/>
   <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="5"/>
   <property name="partitionCount" value="2"/>
   <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5"/>
   <!-- <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="100"/> -->
   <!-- <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="2"/> -->
</bean>

<!-- Declare a JPA entityManagerFactory-->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >

    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="SoopDbProvider" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="SoopDataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>    

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>              
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="packagesToScan">
    <list>
        <value>com.soopproject.main.db</value>
    </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Db initialization bean -->
<bean id="databaseinit" class="com.soopproject.main.db.init.DatabaseInitialization" init-method="init"/>

<!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

**Entities:**

**BaseEntityWithPrimary**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class SoopBaseEntityWithPrimary implements
        Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

}
```

**Language:**

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Language extends BaseEntityWithPrimary {

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String shortname;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String longname;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<TranslationsShort> languageTranslationsShorts;

}
```

**InitMethods**

```
@Autowired
    private UserRepository userrep;

    @Autowired
    private LanguageRepository langrep;

    @Autowired
    private ErrorCodesRepository errorrep;


private void initLanguage() {
    User systemuser = null;
    try {
        systemuser = userrep.findUserByUsername("system");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        DatabaseException exception = new DatabaseReadException(ex);
        exception.writeLog();
    }

    List<Language> languages = new LinkedList<>();

    Language deutsch = new Language();
    deutsch.setCreateUser(systemuser);
    deutsch.setShortname("DE");
    deutsch.setLongname("Deutsch");

    Language english = new Language();
    english.setCreateUser(systemuser);
    english.setShortname("EN");
    english.setLongname("English");

    Language italiano = new Language();
    italiano.setCreateUser(systemuser);
    italiano.setShortname("IT");
    italiano.setLongname("Italiano");

    languages.add(deutsch);
    languages.add(italiano);
    languages.add(english);

    for (Language lang : languages) {
        Language l_help = null;
        try {
            l_help = langrep.findLanguageByShortname(lang.getShortname());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            DatabaseException exception = new DatabaseReadException(ex);
            exception.writeLog();
        }
        if (l_help == null)
            try {
                langrep.saveAndFlush(lang);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                DatabaseException exception = new DatabaseWriteException(e);
                exception.writeLog();
            }
    }
}



private void initErrorCodes() {
    User systemuser = null;
    Language de = null;
    Language it = null;
    Language en = null;

    try {
        systemuser = userrep.findUserByUsername("system");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        DatabaseException exception = new DatabaseReadException(ex);
        exception.writeLog();
    }

    try {
        de = langrep.findLanguageByShortname("DE");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        DatabaseException exception = new DatabaseReadException(ex);
        exception.writeLog();
    }

    try {
        it = langrep.findLanguageByShortname("IT");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        DatabaseException exception = new DatabaseReadException(ex);
        exception.writeLog();
    }

    try {
        en = langrep.findLanguageByShortname("EN");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        DatabaseException exception = new DatabaseReadException(ex);
        exception.writeLog();
    }
```

The problem is that after startup the springapplication and set `<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>` in the method initErrorCodes only the line with *it = langrep.findLanguageByShortname("IT");* finds the data in database. The other 2 calls return null (de = langrep.findLanguageByShortname("DE"); and en = langrep.findLanguageByShortname("EN");). Then i stop the application and look to the database and all data is inserted in the table Language. When i restart the server with `<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>` then all 3 method calls return the data???!?!?! I dont get it. So for sure it's not a problem of the method call. But I cant find the error.

Comment: additional information would be helpful (e.g. how you're initializing the database)

Comment: need to see the code you have tried. Otherwise its difficult to answer or see whats wrong you have done.

Comment: I think only in words is hard to understand, so I insert the code behind. jpa.xml with all spring jpa configuration. The 2 entities and the initmethods. hopefully you can find my error.

jpa.xml:

Comment: You've created MappedSuperClass `SoopBaseEntityWithPrimary` but `Language extends BaseEntityWithPrimary`, Check on that once.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 1 of 3 were found?  Are you querying the data, or accessing a relationship?

It sounds like some sort of caching is occurring.  Some JPA providers enable caching by default, check you cache settings, and ensure you are maintaining bidirectional relationships correctly.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Caching

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Object_corruption.2C_one_side_of_the_relationship_is_not_updated_after_updating_the_other_side

Comment: Now i added the code. It cant be the caching because I didn't configure any cache in my jpa.xml